# BFGMiner No device detected

Tags: miner-configuration, bfgminer

I am completely new to Bitcoin. 
I am trying to connect Slushpool using BFGminer, but its showing some USB device not detected? 
I am a newbie and don't know which device it needs. 
What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to mine just with your plain computer? BFGminer is probably expecting you to use an ASIC, specialized hardware for mining.

Answer (score 1):

The best gaming PCs gave up in 2013. Now you need ASIC hardware to mine. Even 1 TH/s (1000 GH/s) is not fast anymore - I wouldn't buy slower than that. The device bfgminer is looking for is an old and slow ASIC that connects to the USB port of your PC.

Modern miners are stand-alone machines which connect directly to your network, not to your PC. You don't need your PC or bfgminer for the mining. You use a browser on your PC to configure the miner, after that it mines on its own.